# copying file using wget cmd from remote server some times having issue

Tags: linux, networking

having a script(shell) which get zip files from bamboo to linux server, when I execute through bamboo or manually the script some time not copying stuck in middle, After trying 2 or 3 times it copying all binaries.

Comment: Flaky ethernet cable?

Comment: do I need to use any other command instead of wget ?